# document.getElementById onclick only working once per page load

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a link:

```
<a id="lnk" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/path2.pdf?var0=sometext&var1=moretext" onclick="update();"target="_blank">click to export</a>
```

and a JavaScript function in a separate file:

```
function update()
{
    var link = document.getElementById("lnk");
    link.href += "&var2=" + document.getElementById("textareaIdName").value;
    return;
}
```

This is supposed to grab the text from a textarea box in a jsp form to pass into controller for output. It works the first time I click the link, but then if I change the text in the box and click link again it holds the same value from the first click on every other link click until I reload the page regardless of what I change in the text box. The link returns a file download.

How can I keep getting new text from textarea without reloading the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because you are using += each time the link is pressed which will keep concatinating the var2 onto the end of the hyperlink, to make this work you should use:

```
var linkName = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/path/path2.pdf?var0=sometext&var1=moretext";

function update(obj) {
    obj.href = linkName + "&var2=" + document.getElementById("textareaIdName").value;
    return;
} 

<a id="lnk" href="" onclick="update(this);" target="_blank">click to export</a>
```

Comment: But the link's action is invoked (there's no `return false`). Shouldn't that already update the window location to the link's URL?

Comment: if you `CTRL+click` or similar, the page will stay up, if that is what you mean?

Comment: I should clarify The link opens a save as dialog box in a new tab

Comment: this code is working. If you want to change the value of var2 on every click then you can do it by this code easily.

Comment: @jimdrang: Ah, that explains it. This answer should then apply.

Comment: @jimdrang This code is generic enough to work with that too. All it is, is string concatination.

Comment: for var linkname = "linkName?var1=whatever";
my linkName starts with ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and I get an error when I try to put that in a js var in quotes.

Comment: could you please post the code for that in the question? It sounds as if you're trying to use php code in the js file.

Comment: I updated the code to include the new string, this works for me, I hink your problem may be in a different area. Have you tried using a debugging tool such as firebug or the error console to see what the error is?

Comment: it was causing a 404 and resolving the $ and brackets as ascii codes, I think i got it worked out though thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3879/discussion-between-jimdrang-and-serdalis)

Answer (score 2):

In your html:

```
<a ... onclick="return update(this);">click me</a>
```

Passing *this* in the handler means that *this* in the function references the DOM element, so you don't have to use *getElementById*, so the function is:

```
function update(link) {
    link.href = /* whatever */;
}
```

Now you can put the handler on multiple elements without knowing or using the id.